# restore sql localdb with vb.net

Tags: vb.net, restore, localdb

I am trying to retrieve a backup copy of the sql localdb through the environment of .net , but I get error .

the error : RESTORE cannot process database 'C:\Users\Emad-VB\Desktop\KizeN\KizeN\bin\Debug\Data\Data\DataStore.mdf' because it is in use by this session. It is recommended that the master database be used when performing this operation.  RESTORE DATABASE is terminating abnormally.

the sql Query :

RESTORE DATABASE  [C:\Users\Emad-VB\Desktop\KizeN\KizeN\bin\Debug\Data\Data\DataStore.mdf] FROM disk='C:\Users\Emad-VB\Desktop\bac\test.bac'

I tried again to use the database master to make restore but i get this error .

the error :
Incorrect syntax near 'Go'.

the sql Query :

use master

Go

RESTORE DATABASE  [C:\Users\Emad-VB\Desktop\KizeN\KizeN\bin\Debug\Data\Data\DataStore.mdf] FROM disk='C:\Users\Emad-VB\Desktop\bac\test.bac'

This is the code that executes sql queries ....

```
Sub query(ByVal que As String)
    'On Error Resume Next
    Try
        con = New SqlConnection(My.Settings.KConS)
        If con.State = ConnectionState.Closed Then
            con.Open()
        End If
        cmd = New SqlCommand
        cmd.Connection = con
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
        Dim mm As String = " que"
        cmd.CommandText = mm
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
        If con.State = ConnectionState.Open Then
            con.Close()
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
    End Try
End Sub
```

What is the solution to be able to retrieve the local database and Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I see two problems:

1. "GO" is not a t-sql command. It is only meanigful to SQL utilities,
       such as SQL Server Management Studio, so you shouldn't use it in
       code that is being sent directly to the server.
2. I am not sure that you can change the databse within a connection by using "USE
       MASTER". Instead you should create another connection string for
       "master" and use it when you inititalize the connection that will perform the restore.

Comment: i deleted GO from my query and I make anew connection with master database but i still get error :Exclusive access could not be obtained because the database is in use.  RESTORE DATABASE is terminating abnormally. what i should do , thanks

Comment: I found the solution 
First i delete go from my query Then i make new connection with master data base , 
i kill all connection with my restored data base ,make restore using this code :


use master
ALTER DATABASE YourDatabase SET SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE 

 RESTORE DATABASE  YourDatabase   FROM disk='your backup'

ALTER DATABASE YourDatabase SET MULTI_USER

thanks for how help me .